# Windows 7 Home Premium - Factory reset fails

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a Dell-Inspiron 5010 running on windows 7 Home Premium. I want to restore my laptop to factory condition but unfortunately it won't allow me to do it.

If I press F8, then select "Repair your computer", it restarts Windows normally. I want it to show advanced boot option, where I can find the option to restore to the factory image.

I have tried to use a Windows 7 cd, but it only gives me the option to restore to an image made earlier.

I have a hidden image partition at c:/ and the OS at d:/
I don't know how to use the hidden windows image through command prompt to restore.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Contact [Dell support](https://www.dell.com/support/Contents/us/en/dhs/category/Contact-Information/Technical-Support?~ck=mn). You may need to order yourself a restore DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Dell have a way of making it difficult to do reinstalls etc. Either get their recovery DVD or, what i did was install ubuntu, works on anything.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to restore from recovery image using Ubuntu live cd?

Comment: I'm assuming based on previous experience that there is a prtition set aside for recovery. This being the case it should be possible to boot into live CD and start the recovery process from there.

worth adding an additional plugin in may be required to run win software on linux e.g WINE. 

At work at the moment so not really able to look into this too much but hope you get some useful info lol.